# Display "none found" text if all data attributes in list are equal to "off"

Tags: javascript

I'm newer to Javascript and am working on building a simple filter for static data. I want to be able to display text if there are no options that have the selected tag options. How could I do this?

The user needs to be able to select multiple filters at the same time. If no combination of selected filters exist then it should display text that states "nothing found".

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  var button = e.target;
  
  if (button.getAttribute('data-reset') === 'true') {
    // Reset the filters
    var filter = button.getAttribute('data-filter');
    resetFilter(filter);
  } else {
    // Filter the tag
    var filter = button.getAttribute('data-filter');
    var tag    = button.getAttribute('data-filter-tag');
    filterTag(filter, tag);
  }
});

// Filter tag
function filterTag (filter, tag) {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.' + filter + ' > li');

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var itemTags = items[i].getAttribute('data-tags');

    // Catch case with no tags
    if (itemTags != null) {
      if (itemTags.indexOf(tag) < 0) {
        items[i].setAttribute('data-toggle', 'off');
      }
    }
  }
}


// Reset filters
function resetFilter (filter) {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('.' + filter + ' > li');

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].setAttribute('data-toggle', 'on');
  }
}

<button data-filter="ping" data-reset="true">Reset</button>
<button data-filter="ping" data-filter-tag="a">Show A</button>
<button data-filter="ping" data-filter-tag="b">Show B</button>
<button data-filter="ping" data-filter-tag="c">Show C</button>
<button data-filter="ping" data-filter-tag="z">Show Z</button>

<ul id="ddlList" class="ping">
  <li value="3" data-tags="a b">Apple</li>
  <li value="5" data-tags="a f r">Axe</li>
  <li value="8" data-tags="a">Aventador</li>
  <li value="2" data-tags="b g z">Boomerang</li>
  <li value="4" data-tags="b">Bath</li>
  <li value="6" data-tags="b c">Bar</li>
  <li value="7" data-tags="c a">Car</li>
  <li value="1" data-tags="c m t">Carrot</li>
</ul>
```

Here is my script -

https://jsfiddle.net/areb81/uynsvhr8/1/

Comment: Are you using jQuery, or pure javascript?

Comment: Please post your JavaScript here, not a link elsewhere.

Comment: @JeffB Pure javascript

Comment: @Phix Javascript added

Comment: @BrynnA Went ahead and posted the answer =). I edited it so it is pretty in line with what you are looking for. Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This code was adopted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58038563/2096053) answer and changed to pure JavaScript.

The following should do the trick!

EDIT: Changed to have the "Reset" button and labels on what is shown.

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('button')

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tag")).forEach(el => {
  el.style.display = 'none';
});

btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', event => {
    const filter = event.target.dataset.filter;
    if (filter === 'reset') {
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("btn")).forEach(el => {
        el.setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
      });
      btn.setAttribute('data-active', 'true');
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("item")).forEach(el => {
  el.style.display = 'block';
});
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("tag")).forEach(el => {
  el.style.display = 'none';
});
    } else {
      document.getElementById('buttonReset').setAttribute('data-active', 'false');
      btn.setAttribute('data-active', 'true');
      filterData();
    }
  });
});

function filterData() {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("item")).forEach(el => {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  });

  var filter = "";
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button[data-active='true']")).forEach(btn => {
    filter += "[data-tag*='" + btn.dataset.filter + "']";
  });
  var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div" + filter));
  if (items.length > 0) {
    items.forEach(el => {
      el.style.display = 'block';
    });
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button[data-active='true']")).forEach(btn => {
      Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("span[data-tag='" + btn.dataset.filter + "']")).forEach(el => {
        el.style.display = 'block';
      });
    });
  } else {
    document.getElementById('reset').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
.selectionContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.selectionContainer span {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #ddf;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
  <button class="btn btn-default active" data-filter="reset" data-active="true" id="buttonReset">Reset</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-filter="tag_1">Tag 1</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-filter="tag_2">Tag 2</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-filter="tag_3">Tag 3</button>
  <button class="btn btn-default" data-filter="tag_4">Tag 4</button>
</div>
<div class="selectionContainer">
  <span class="item tag" data-tag="reset" id="reset">None</span>
  <span class="item tag" data-tag="tag_1">Tag 1</span>
  <span class="item tag" data-tag="tag_2">Tag 2</span>
  <span class="item tag" data-tag="tag_3">Tag 3</span>
  <span class="item tag" data-tag="tag_4">Tag 4</span>
</div>
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item" data-tag="['tag_2', 'tag_3']">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 2 &amp; Tag 3</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="['tag_1', 'tag_4']">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 1 &amp; Tag 4</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_2">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_3">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 3</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_4">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 4</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_3">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 3</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_2">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_1">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 1</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_3">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 3</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_4">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 4</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_2">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 2</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_3">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 3</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item" data-tag="tag_4">
    <div class="item-content">
      <h4>Tag 4</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It does need to be able to select multiple tags. So, a user could select both tag 1 and tag 2 at the same time. Then if they select a combination that is not tagged with selected tags it would display "none found".

Comment: @BrynnA Oh I see, your question was very unclear on this, I would update that.

Comment: sorry about that. Added these details to my question.

Comment: @BrynnA I have updated the answer, is this what you were asking?

Comment: Yes! But the reset button doesn't appear to work now for me.

Comment: @BrynnA Please try again? Reset is working fine for me. Or is reset supposed to show all items?

Comment: Reset would go back to showing all items.

Comment: @BrynnA Try now! =)

Comment: Awesome - this is perfect! Thanks so much for your help =)

Comment: @BrynnA No problem! Since you are new, just fyi, when you feel somebody has correctly answered your question, you should mark it as the answer so future people can easily see the correct information. It also gives you reputation and gives you the ability to do more things on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are attempting to do I believe.  Here I added some CSS to show what was toggled.  I took liberty to make the event handlers specific to the desire as well.

I could easily see the scenario  where a second button click would "clear" a filter - or these might be checkboxes instead of buttons.

Some of this code can also be consolidated but left if somewhat less so for clarity of the refactor I did.
Note you could instead of a lime color set the display of those `display:none;` in the CSS

```js
function handlePingClick(e) {
  //same thing  console.log(e.target, this);
  let filter = this.dataset.filter;
  let tag = this.dataset.filterTag;
  filterTag(filter, tag);
}

function handleResetClick(e) {
  let filter = this.dataset.filter;
  resetFilter(filter);
}

// Filter tag
function filterTag(filter, tag) {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.' + filter + ' > li');

  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    let itemTags = items[i].dataset.tags;
    // Catch case with no tags
    if (!!itemTags && itemTags.length > 0 && itemTags.indexOf(tag) < 0) {
      items[i].dataset.toggle = 'off';
    }
  }
}

// Reset filters
function resetFilter(filter) {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.' + filter + ' > li');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].dataset.toggle = 'on';
  }
}

const filterButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-filter-tag]'));
for (const btn of filterButtons) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', handlePingClick);
}
const resetButton = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-reset]'));
for (const btn of resetButton) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', handleResetClick);
}
```

```css
[data-toggle="off"] {
  color: blue;
}

[data-toggle="on"] {
  color: lime;
}
```

```html
<button data-filter="ping" data-reset="true">Reset</button>
<button data-filter="ping" data-filter-tag="a">Show A</button>
<button data-filter="ping" data-filter-tag="b">Show B</button>
<button data-filter="ping" data-filter-tag="c">Show C</button>
<button data-filter="ping" data-filter-tag="z">Show Z</button>

<ul id="ddlList" class="ping">
  <li value="3" data-tags="a b">Apple</li>
  <li value="5" data-tags="a f r">Axe</li>
  <li value="8" data-tags="a">Aventador</li>
  <li value="2" data-tags="b g z">Boomerang</li>
  <li value="4" data-tags="b">Bath</li>
  <li value="6" data-tags="b c">Bar</li>
  <li value="7" data-tags="c a">Car</li>
  <li value="1" data-tags="c m t">Carrot</li>
</ul>
```